# How to transparently realize clean up action when the node process ends

Tags: node.js

I need to perform a cleanup action when the Node process exits.

I know I can use `process.on('exit')`, `process.on('Unhandled|Rejected Exception')` and `process.on('<signal>')` to listen such events.

However, I would like not bind any of this, for these reasons:

- If I bind to [`process.on('exit')`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/process.html#process_event_exit), I should not be doing any async operations, which is not reliable when you need to write out a message over a socket or a pipe (afaik).
- If I bind to [`process.on('some exceptions')`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception), I have to print the error like a normal node process. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.
- If I bind [`process("SIGINT")`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/process.html#process_signal_events), I have to exit the process manually. What if someone else is listening too, or what if I can't know the exit status of the node process?

Any idea what I should do?

In my particular use case I will spawn a server, and when Node exits, I need to send it a signal to tell it to quit. And I would like this to be as transparent as possible for the module-consumer.

Thanks!

Comment: If your server is just an entity that you create without spawning a new process, Node should be able to take care of that for you. However, I assume that you are, in fact, spawning a new process, which might not even be a Node process.

Comment: to clarify my specific use case, it s a server i spawn via the child_process, but i loose the control of the process. I m left with the server socket address only to send it a message to tell the server to quit too.

Comment: What module are you using to spawn the server process? I would reason that unless you also want to be able to connect to a remote server, you should be able to create the local server in such a way as to keep the process ID (and thus send it a synchronous kill signal). What purpose is your server serving?

Comment: nop, unfortunately this won t work. it s a child_process i spawn and loose control of it (a bit like detached, but this time it is really unavailable). I can t use cp.kill(signal). I don't think i can use channel either. As the server-process is elevated, i don t think i can kill it from the userland via taskkill. I ll go for a file to watch on the server, which tells it to die once the file is found, and use writeFileSync on the client to properly pass process.on('exit'). Thanks for the ideas !

Answer (score 0):

## Just let your client process hang up.

In your use case, you mention that you have a socket going from your nodejs module to your server, and you want to kill the server when the module exits because the server has nothing else to do. No matter which way you spin it, there is no foolproof way for a client to tell a server that it's done with them by sending a message (since the client can die unexpectedly), but when they die, any connections that they have opened will close (it might take a few minutes in the case of an unhandled exception, but they will eventually close).

As long as you keep the socket open, the server will be able to tell that the connection is still alive. No traffic need actually be passing between the two programs, but the server can tell all the same. And, when the socket is closed (because the other end has exited), the socket on the server will get the [`socket.on('end')`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/net.html#net_event_end) event. At that point, the server can clean up resources, and its empty event loop will automatically shut it down.

Comment: This can work if the server has a well-defined job to realize. If it s expected to receive a job, __or not__, ie an undefined set of job to realize. That strategy is unfortunately ineffective. thanks again.

Comment: Well, you could cause the server, at the beginning, to sit idle until you send it a request to start its job, and in case the client process dies before that happens, then you can set a 1-minute timeout on the server that will cause it to close itself if it doesn't receive any work.